# Check If Cell Has Two Number Same

Tags: excel, vba

can someone tell me how to check a cell, A1 has contains 2 identical numbers?
Example cell A1 = 1124. This the what i meant contains 2 identical numbers and if so, B1 will be "Yes" Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, the quickest way I see to get there: convert it to a string and then run [this function](http://www.codevba.com/visual-basic-source-code/vb-string/count_occurrences_in_a_string.htm) for each of the characters 0 through 9.  It's not pretty but it works.

Comment: Just curious. Which Excel version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Excel 2010 (Not tested in Excel 2007) then you don't need VBA for this. You can use this Formula in `B1` and copy it down.

```
=IF(LOWER(A1)<>SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),LOWER(1),"",2),"Yes",
 IF(LOWER(A1)<>SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),LOWER(2),"",2),"Yes",
 IF(LOWER(A1)<>SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),LOWER(3),"",2),"Yes",
 IF(LOWER(A1)<>SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),LOWER(4),"",2),"Yes",
 IF(LOWER(A1)<>SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),LOWER(5),"",2),"Yes",
 IF(LOWER(A1)<>SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),LOWER(6),"",2),"Yes",
 IF(LOWER(A1)<>SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),LOWER(7),"",2),"Yes",
 IF(LOWER(A1)<>SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),LOWER(8),"",2),"Yes",
 IF(LOWER(A1)<>SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),LOWER(9),"",2),"Yes",
 IF(LOWER(A1)<>SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),LOWER(0),"",2),"Yes",
 "No"))))))))))
```

**Explanation**

The formula checks from `0 - 9` in the excel cell if that particular number is re-curring.

**ScreenSHot**

[image]

**VBA Version**:

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Does2NumbersMatch(Range("A1"))
End Sub

Function Does2NumbersMatch(rng As Range)
    Dim i As Long

    Does2NumbersMatch = "No"

    For i = 0 To 9
        isMatch = Application.Evaluate("=IF(LOWER(" & rng.Address & ")<>SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(" & _
                  rng.Address & "),LOWER(" & i & "),"""",2),""Yes"",""No"")")
        If isMatch = "Yes" Then
            Does2NumbersMatch = "Yes"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Hi all, I'm using excel 07 and I need to use vba to do it. Thanks

Comment: In that case see the ink given by @RobertHarvey. That should be good enough for you :)

Comment: @user388197: BTW The above formula can also be used in VBA

Comment: @Philip: That will not work in excel 2003 as you can only have 7 nested Ifs. test for 1002

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes I realised my version at home is different. Nevertheless, I checked and [MSDN Library: Excel 2007 Formula Nesting Levels is increased to 64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa730921(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. May I know how can I alter the code so that I can check whether the number contains 2 pair of identical numbers? Example 1122, 5588, 7722. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user388197: Is this a program for Lottery (Doubles)? :)

Comment: Not lottery, but lucky draw. Customer with their last 4 receipt number with one pair of number will get one prize. Those with two pairs, will get two. Thank you.

Comment: @user388197: Yes I know because I created an app for Doubles for this lottery(lucky draw) :) To check for doubles, you have to check for the numbers in sets of 2. For example lets say the number is ABCD then you have to check for AB(A=B?), CD(C=D?)

Comment: Thank you for the info. Now I know where to start with.